# Why "tsc -v" in cmd doesn't shows typescript version?

Tags: typescript

In my work pc ,"tsc -v" doesn't show the typescript version ,it shows this . [image]

and "where tsc" shows this [image]

I don't understand the "tsc -v" commands problem. Can anyone tell what seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is running the JS `tsc.js` file. I am guessing what you want is `tsc.exe`. so either remove the node location from the path or type `tsc.exe` when you want to use the compiler from the command line.

or do this:

Removing the npm PATH entry or changing the npm PATH to point to:

`......\node_modules\typescript\bin\`

instead of:

`...... \node_modules\typescript\lib\`

Comment: removing node location from path gives typescript error.